# Python: What is the easiest way to define a circle and check if a point lies in it

Tags: python, math, geometry, pi

I want to define a circle of set radius, ask the user for input of the x and y coordinate and then check if the point lies within the circle.

This is what I am using right now (distance formula).

```
r = 1024
xc = r
yc = 6

def distance(x,y):
    return ((x - xc)^2 + (y - yc)^2)^1/2

def check(x,y):
    if distance(x,y) > r:
        return 1;
    else:
        return 0;
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Yes, by not using Python at all. This also includes using numpy which is not written in Python.

Comment: you have to use ** instead of ^  - 2^2 gives 0, 2**2 gives 4

Comment: First you can start by working with squared values to avoid the squareroot calculation, but honestly it's not a big improvement

Comment: Also depending on your context you may want to choose different metric. For example if you are working on sequence convergence then you can use topologically equivalent metric `x+y` which is way easier to compute.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work too:

```
if (x-xc)**2+(y-yc)**2 < r**2:
   return 1
else:
   return 0
```

but it's not very more efficient than your code , a little improve

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your check a little bit by removing the `if .. else` as:

```
def check(x,y):
    return ((x - xc)**2 + (y - yc)**2) < r**2
```